# VSCode Source Control Icon view has too many entries; how do I reduce them?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a newbie at VSCode and Git. After seeing videos, I understand  using Git from the command line.

I did a Git init on an existing project folder. 5 items in the directory were shown as untracked when I execute a git status in the terminal.

When I click on the Source Control Icon in the sidebar there are over 300 items shown as untracked??

When I do a git add in the terminal for each of the 5 items previously shown as untracked, the view from the Source Control icon now shows over 300 items marked as "A".

Why must I be shown all these 300+ items when in the terminal I am only working with 5? I'd like to see only the 5 items in the terminal listed in The Source Control view. Having over 300 items is overwhelming.

Is there a way to stop so many items from being displayed in the Source Control view?  Do I even want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can show git changes as a tree (from Settings):

```js
"scm.defaultViewMode": "tree"
```

There's also an icon to toggle it:

[image]

If that's not what you are asking for, then add the files that you want to ignore to the `.gitignore` file to exclude them from the SCM view.